# How to get PHP array results using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Below are a couple of queries that ultimately build an array.

```
if(isset($_POST['getarray'])){
    try{
        $ret = array();
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT groupdate, groupid
                                    FROM participationtemp
                                    WHERE memberid = :memberid
                                    AND groupid = :groupid
                                    ORDER BY groupdate, groupid DESC');
        $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION['memberid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row){
            $attenddate = $row[0];
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT h.clientid, attend, attend_date
                                        FROM history AS h 
                                        INNER JOIN suspended AS s on s.clientid = h.clientid                                    
                                        WHERE h.memberid = :memberid  
                                        AND h.groupid = :groupid
                                        AND attend_date = :attenddate
                                        AND suspend = "N"');
            $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':attenddate', $attenddate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $row ) {
                array_push($ret, ['id' => $row[0], 'gdate' => $row[2]]);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($ret);
        exit();
    } catch (PDOException $ex){
            mail_error($ex);
    }
}
```

After returning to JQuery, `alert(re);` shows I successfully created the array.

```
success:function(re){
    alert(re);
```

[image]

But I'm having trouble accessing the array data. Without success, this is what i've tried:

```
data = $.parseJSON(re);

$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    alert(i + "=" + val);
});
```

and this:

```
data = $.parseJSON(re);

$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if(i == "id"){
        alert(i + "=" + val);
    }
    if(i == "gdate"){
        alert(i + "=" + val);
    }
});
```

I've also tried `dot notation`.

```
$.each(re.id, function(i, val) {
    alert(i + "=" + val);
    }
});
$.each(re.gdate, function(i, val) {                             
    alert(i + "=" + val);                               
});
```

I've never used JSON before and don't understand why I can't retrieve the array data. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots are evil. Please copy-paste all text outputs.

Comment: What did the alert contain with your first try? The JSON represents an array of objects, so I would expect you to see something like ```0=[Object object]```. Is this what happened or did the alert not even show?

Comment: `I've also tried dot notation.` - where is it? and please post the output of `alert(i + "=" + val);`.

Comment: can you initialize your json data with `var re` statically? let me know.

Comment: like `var re = 'your json data';` and then ready for use  `data = $.parseJSON(re);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code checks whether `re` is a string, or an object. The latter is possible if [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method is used with "json" `dataType`. Also, jQuery is capable of parsing JSON automatically, if the response MIME type is `application/json` (the `Content-Type` HTTP header), particularly. So it is a good idea to check if `re` has been parsed by jQuery.

```
var d = typeof re === 'string' ? JSON.parse(re)  : re;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  console.log("id = ", d[i].id,
              "gdate = ", d[i].gdate);
}
```

I'd recommend returning the appropriate content type from PHP:

```
    header ('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($ret);
    exit();
```

Comment: Adding the header did the trick. I appreciate your insight, Rusian. This has really helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(re, function(i, val) {
    alert(val.id + "=" + val.gdate);
});
```

Comment: This may also require ```dataType``` to be set to ```"json"``` in the ```$.ajax``` config.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :)

```js
// Json in string format
var jsonString = '[{"id":"1", "gdate":"2016-10-13"},{"id":"2", "gdate":"2016-10-13"},{"id":"3", "gdate":"2016-10-13"},{"id":"4", "gdate":"2016-10-13"},{"id":"5", "gdate":"2016-10-13"},{"id":"6", "gdate":"2016-10-13"}]';

// Convert string to json object
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// Iterate over json object
jQuery.each(json, function(index, value) {
  console.log(index, value);
});

// Simple access to attribute in json object
console.log('json[1][\'id\'] = ', json[1]['id']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```